# PHP reuseable delete row with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

My code repeats for everytable. The ajax function and file delete.php repeat everytime I want to delete. Example I have 100 table in mysql, I have to make 100 delete.php

Can I use 1 delete.php for all, same with ajax function as well?

PHP code:

```
echo"<td><a href='#' onclick='doConfirm(".$id.")'>Delete</a></td>";
```

Ajax code:

```
function doConfirm(id)

    {
        var xhttp; 

        var ok = confirm("Are you sure to Delete?")
        if (ok)
        {

          xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById('show1').innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
            }


          }

          xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?id=" + id,true);
           xhttp.send();
        }
}


delete.php
$f0=$_GET['id'];
delete($f0);
```

Comment: the answer below is correct. But may I suggest that you start to use jquery to minimize your amount of custom coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass another param to `onclick='doConfirm(".$id.")'` as tablename and then pass then table name as query string on GET method and then in a single delete.php file you can delete from that which you have passed.

for Ex: `echo"<td><a href='#' onclick='doConfirm(".$id.", "table1")'>Delete</a></td>";`

**Ajax**

```
function doConfirm(id, tableName)

    {
        var xhttp; 

        var ok = confirm("Are you sure to Delete?")
        if (ok)
        {

          xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById('show1').innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
            }


          }

          xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?id=" + id + "table=" + tableName,true);
           xhttp.send();
        }
}
```

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single master file which will do as per requirment..
Example , to delete in tbl_book , our url will be

```
xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?target=book&id=" + id,true);
```

Now in delete.php , do it in switch or if else block

```
$target=$_REQUEST['target'];
switch(target)
{
case 'book': //your delete query for tbl_book
break;
case 'emp': //your delete query for tbl_emp
break;
}
```

The above examples is just giving an idea to do it ..Change as per requirment